# When judge the iterable got NameError: name 'Iterable' is not defined

Tags: python

I follow the tutorial:

[image]

In my PyCharm I follow the tutorial:

[image]

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/adob/TestPython/test02/passwd.py", line 19, in 
>       bool = isinstance({}, Iterable)
>   NameError: name 'Iterable' is not defined

Comment: you should not use images when you can use text

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I use image because there is the red under-line here. use code can not show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import Iterable

bool = isinstance({},Iterable)
print(bool)
```

Output

True

Comment: In Python 3.7 it is marked deprecated. Use `from collections.abc import Iterable` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The Iterable is in the `collections` module, you should import it.

```
from collections import Iterable
```

Comment: In Py3, the other option is the same import from the `typing` module but given the `print` statement assume the OP is using Py2.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2:

```
from collections import Iterable
```

Python 3:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

Or both:

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Iterable
except ImportError:
    from collections import Iterable
```